# re-execute the MVC pipeline with another route from a resource filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

### TL;DR

How do I reinvoke the MVC routing engine and MvcHandler from a IAsyncResourceFilter, using another route? I basically want to invoke the pipeline twice (in parallel?).

### background

I'm building a [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) implementation for an ASP.Net Core API. To implement HAL, a returned resource should be able to embed other resources in order to reduce the chattiness between client and server. A response would look like this:

```
{
   "_links": {
      "self": {
         "href": "/myResource/1"
      }
   },
   "name": "myResource",
   "foo": "bar",
   "_embedded": {
      "relatedResource": {
         "_links": {
            "self": {
               "href": "/relatedResources/5"
            }
         },
         "name": "relatedResource",
         "baz": "foo"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to decouple the embedding of resources from the controllers, so I figured I would simply

1. invoke the MVC pipeline for the original request.
2. invoke the MVC pipeline for the resources to embed.
3. embed the the resources from 2 to the response of 1.

If this would work, this would enable caching of the resources to embed as well as authorization and what not.

I want to use a ResourceFilter, because I need to access the controller and action the request will be routed to, in order to know what resources should be embedded. So I need access to the `ControllerActionDescriptor`.

```
public class HalEmbed : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Implementation not useful for question
        var actionToEmbed = GetActionToEmbed();

        await next();

        // TODO: How do I do this?
        var embedResult = await ReExecutePipelineHere(actionToEmbed.Url);

        // Will be magic if I know how to do the above.
        Embed(embedResult, context.Result);
    }
}
```

This diagram I found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-types) implies it should be possible to re-execute the pipeline from a resource filter somehow:

[image: MVC filter Pipeline]

So how do I re-execute the MVC pipeline with another url, while also being able to execute the pipeline for the current url?

Answer (score 2):

The image you are looking at does not really show that they can re-execute the pipeline. What the image is trying to say instead is that the resource filter can short-circuit the pipeline (e.g. by returning a cached result), and that it will be executed after the result filters again (e.g. to cache the results for later requests).

Re-executing the MVC filter pipeline itself is not possible. This is mainly because there is no way to reconfigure the execution context for a separate execution.

However, what you *can* do is re-execute the middleware pipeline. The [`ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.5/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) does that for example to display the result of the exception handling endpoint instead when it catches an exception. It does that by changing the request parameters (e.g. the `HttpContext.Request.Path`) and invoking the middleware pipeline again (i.e. `next()`).

Since middleware acts on the HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects directly, of course this means that the logic has to be a lot more low-level. You cannot for example just take an `ObjectResult` and adjust that result to include another value. Instead, you will have to work on top of the already serialized JSON result.

Unfortunately, while this would theoretically work, I would actually expect this to be rather painful to implement. After all, you would be deserializing results you just serialized just to serialize them again etc. That will probably also have effects on the performance.

Instead, what I would suggest you is to add another abstraction layer that basically moves the responsibility to construct the result away from the ASP.NET Core framework. Instead of relying on that to build your result, and then having to execute it again to fill your referenced links, call something else instead that can build both your result and the referenced links separately. So the controller action would then just be an orchestrator for that.

You could probably do that with [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR), a rather simple but powerful mediator implementation. It would allow you to represent your logic compleletely outside of ASP.NET Core and its HTTP-based concept (which would be great for testability too) while also giving you the possibility to recursively call itself (to place results within your results). And it also comes with its own pipeline concept that would allow you to actually abstract that away into a common component as well, so that each request handler would only have to care about the immediate request layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to let this sink in for a while. I created a POC with a piece of middleware that creates a custom `HttpContext` with custom request and response and custom request and response features. For the embedding part, I re-execute the 'next' `RequestDelegate` with that custom `HttpContext` and for a simple api. Added a processing pipeline in between to construct the 'resource' embedding and linking.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to re-invoke (part of) the MVC pipeline, by adding custom middleware that passes a custom `HttpContext` to the calls for adding embedded resources. I'm not sure whether this allows me to leverage response caching and authorization to the full extent yet, but in a simple api, it does re-invoke the MVC pipeline.

It is, however, rather cumbersome. Here's some pseudo-code below to show how it may be done.

```
public class HalMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate next;
    public HalMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // We need the MVC pipeline after our custom middleware.
        this.next = next
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Invoke the 'normal' pipeline first.
        // Note that the mvc middleware would serialize the response...
        // Prevent that by injecting a custom IActionResultExecutor<ObjectResult>, 
        // that sets the ActionResult to the context instead of serializing.
        await this.next(context);

        // Our objectresultexecutor added some information on the HttpContext.
        if (!context.Items.TryGetValue("HalFormattingContext", out object formatObject)
            ||!(formatObject is HalFormattingContext halFormattingContext))
        {
            logger.LogDebug("Hal formatting context not found, other formatters are handling this response.");
            return;
        }

        // some code to create a resource object from the result.
        var rootResource = ConstructRootResource(halFormattingContext.ObjectResult);
        halFormattingContext.ObjectResult.Value = rootResource;

        // some code to figure out which actions/routes to embed.
        var toEmbeds = GetRoutesToEmbed(halFormattingContext.ActionContext);
        var requestFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
        foreach (var toEmbed in toEmbeds)
        {
            var halRequestFeature = new HalHttpRequestFeature(requestFeature)
            {
                Method = "GET",
                Path = toEmbed.Path
            };

            // The HalHttpContext creates a custom request and response in the constructor 
            // and creates a new feature collection with custom request and response features.
            var halContext = new HalHttpContext(context, halRequestFeature);
            await this.next(halContext);

            // Now the custom ObjectResultExecutor set the ActionResult to a property of the custom HttpResponse.
            var embedActionResult = ((HalHttpResponse)halContext.Response).ObjectResult;

            // some code to embed the new actionresult.
            Embed(rootResource, embedActionResult, toEmbed);
        }

        // Then invoke the default ObjectResultExecutor to serialize the new result.
        await halFormattingContext.DefaultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(
            halFormattingContext.ActionContext,
            halFormattingContext.ObjectResult);
    }
}
```